# segmentation fault when using double brackets with printf

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, printf, comma-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define POOLNAME_FMT "Hello"

void main() {

 printf((POOLNAME_FMT "Cannot allocate %d bytes" POOLNAME_FMT "in pool not enough memory",5));

}
```

Why does it give *segmentation fault* when I use double brackets with `printf`. i.e. `printf(( ));`?

Answer (score 11):

Because `(a, b)` is actually a single value. It calculates `a` and `b` and returns the value of `b`.

So what you are doing is basically:

```
/* calculate before `,` and ignore */
POOLNAME_FMT "Cannot allocate %d bytes" POOLNAME_FMT "in pool not enough memory";
/* call printf with after `,` */
printf(5);
```

Which is clearly wrong.

---

When you write `func(a, b)` as a function call, C knows to send `a` and `b` as separate arguments to `func`. When you say `func((a, b))`, you are explicitely saying `(a, b)` is **one** value and that the result (i.e., the value of `b`) should be sent to `func` as a single argument.

If you compile with warnings, and if your compiler is nice to you, it could warn you about this. If your compiler is not nice, it should still complain that you are giving an `int` where a `const char *` is expected.

If using `gcc`, I highly recommend compiling with `-Wall`, always.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) without realizing it:

```
( ... "in pool not enough memory",5)
                                 ^
```

since the *comma operator* will evaluate its left operand and discard the result and then evaluate and return the right operand, you end up with:

```
printf( 5 ) ;
```

which will attempt to convert an `int` to a `const char *restrict` for the format string, which will almost surely not point to valid memory. Without the `()`, the `,` would have just been a separator for the function arguments.

The `()` is an expression in this context; if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.1` *Primary expressions*, we have:

```
( expression )
```

therefore the `,` is treated as an operator while we can see from section `6.5.2` *Postfix operators*:

```
postfix-expression ( argument-expression-listopt )
argument-expression-list:
   assignment-expression
   argument-expression-list , assignment-expression
                            ^
```

The `,` is just a separator in a function call.

Having warnings enabled should have helped here, `gcc` gives me a few warnings for this program:

> warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]

and

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>       note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: @minitech thank you for the grammatical fixes, any particular reason to prefer using `[]()` for links?

Comment: It’s shorter and looks better, but the important change there was to use the HTTPS version of Wikipedia. And no problem!

Comment: @minitech hmmm, why should we prefer to use the HTTPS version?

Answer (score 2):

This is because printf is a function, which will accept its arguments in single parenthesës, and the second set of parenthesēs is actually opening up a subexpression:

```
(string "string" string "string" , 5)
```

The first four strings are concatenated at compile time, yielding:

```
("string", 5)
```

This is then evaluated:

- `"string"` evaluates to a pointer to the first character of it
- *a*`,`*b* evaluates *a* first, then throws the result away, then evaluates and returns *b*
- `5` evaluates to an integer constant 5

So in effect, you're calling:

```
printf(5);
```

(This is because the string has no side effects.)

Something like this, however, would work:

```
printf((POOLNAME_FMT "Cannot allocate %d bytes" POOLNAME_FMT "in pool not enough memory"),5);
```

Note how the comma and the five were moved to outside of the parenthesised subexpression.